# String not recognized in function definition

Tags: string, function

I am trying to code the number of occurences of 'e' in a particular string but it is giving me error while defining the function as it says **string is not defined in this scope** and occurence_e(which is my user-def function) to be not declared in this scope as well.
Following is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
void occurence_e(string);
using namespace std;
int main(){
 string input; 
cout<<"Enter any name"<<endl;
cin>>input;
occurence_e(input);
    return 0;
}

void occurence_e(string input){
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input.at(i)=='e'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"No. of times e comes in this name is "<<count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward reference uses `string`, so move `using namespace std;` above it.

```
using namespace std;
void occurence_e(string);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution sir